# Reading a text file: 'If' character store information after character

Tags: c#, text, xna, stream, streamreader

What I'm trying to do is read in a text file that holds all the stats associated with a car part, such as weight, acceleration, top speed etc. I want to be able to simply write in the text file:
W 5
A 10
T 20

Therefore i need to check if there is a character and if so grab the value after it. This is what I'm trying so far:

public virtual void ReadStats(string selectedModel)
{
            List lines = new List();

```
        using (var ModelInfo = new FileStream(selectedModel, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ModelInfo))
            {
                float input;

                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("W"))
                    {
                       //Save the value after the character.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason it isn't even getting into the 'if' it seems to not read the 'W' character.
Also how would i go about grabbing the value after the character.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're reading _two_ lines before you check for the "W" (maybe try initializing `string line = null` instead of the first `reader.ReadLine()` call) EDIT: And depending on your file content/usage, perhaps consider just using the `File.ReadAllLines` method to greatly simplify the process of reading the text file content.

Comment: are you tossing the first line on purpose?  Also, are you checking the value of `line` to ensure you're reading correctly?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair initializing line = null now allows the if function to operate correctly. Thing is i don't want to read all the lines as the text file also holds data for the vertices of the part models. Any idea how I would be able to take the value after 'W' and save it to a variable?

Comment: @adtither: Sure, take a look at the various [string methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (especially `IndexOf` and `SubString`), [split methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx) (say, splitting by the space character " "), and [parsing methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4w53z0y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert those strings into numeric integer types. Give those a shot, see how it goes, and if you have a specific question about how to use those, post another question _specifically_ about that one aspect.

Comment: Using Substring at the moment will look into a more efficient way of doing it. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason why you are not using substring?

```
var test = line.substring("W")
```

Put this in your if block.

Comment: Cant use substring("W"), it's expecting an int in the brackets. What exactly would this allow me to do?

Comment: Actually spot on mate that did the job, just had to use an index and length. Cheers.